# Start for loop permutations at specific number?

Tags: python, permutation, python-itertools

Sorry if I didn't word that correctly. I have a script that gets the permutations of cities (yes, those are names of US cities!) however I already have(for example) the first 90 already saved, I was trying to figure out how to start the script at permutation number 91, so I don't have to restart the process. Below is my script. This is just an example of some of the cities, the real list contains many more cities but I shortened.

```
import itertools

x1 = ['Hell', 'Frankenstein', 'Accident', 'Why', 'Okay']
x2 = ['BaldHead', 'Worms', 'SatansKingdom', 'Dinosaur', 'Coward']
x3 =['Dummer', 'DingDong', 'Chugwater', 'BoogerHole', 'Cut&Shoot']

y = itertools.product(x1, x2, x3)

def produce_partially_set(wordlist):
    wordlist.insert(0, 'Boring')
    wordlist.insert(3, 'WhatCheer')
    wordlist.insert(5, 'Zap')
    wordlist.append('Fries')
    return wordlist

for i in y:
    mystring = ' '.join(i)
    splitstrings = mystring.split()
    perms = produce_partially_set(splitstrings)
    seed = ' '.join(perms)
    print(seed)
```

I'd like the script to start with the 91st permutation like below

```
#1 = Boring Hell BaldHead WhatCheer Dummer Zap Fries
#91 = Boring Why Dinosaur WhatCheer Dummer Zap Fries
```

I looked up nth_permutation in more itertools but I was thrown off because the way my script is setup.

Comment: `nth_permutation` won't help you because it's for the Nth *permutation*, and you don't have permutations, you have a Cartesian product. You want... `nth_product`. If you know how many "products" (individual results from the Cartesian product) there are, and you have this function to get the nth of them, it should be trivial to iterate from there to the end, and it should be clear from the documentation how the result of `nth_product` fits directly in to your `produce_partially_set` code. (By the way, it seems rather pointless to join and then re-split the `product` results.)

Answer (score 2):

90 is a small number of elements. Unless you're doing this repeatedly in performance-critical code, you should not notice to cost of just regenerating and ignoring the first 90 permutations.

You can conveniently skip the first 90 elements of an iterator using [`itertools.islice`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice):

```
for x in itertools.islice(y, 90, None):
   ...
```